# Bootstrap slider range value text boxes

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, slider, bootstrap-slider

So basically I tried to achieve what's in this jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/FPCRb/
Have a slider bar for a range of values and two text boxes as well.

Here is my HTML table:

```
<table class="table borderless">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>+/-</th>
        <th>Searches</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="optradio" class="custom"> ALL</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="optradio2" class="custom2"> ALL</td>
        <td><input id="slider" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="10" data-slider-max="1000" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,1000]" data-slider-id="RC" id="R"/></td>
        <td><button id="reset" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Reset</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="custom-selector"> Rank 1-10</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="custom-selector2"> Up</td>

        <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-inline col-xs-1 sliderValue" style="width: 60px" placeholder="From"  data-index="0" value="10">
          <label class="col-xs-1" style="font-size: 22px">→</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-inline col-xs-1 sliderValue" style="width: 60px" placeholder="To"  data-index="1" value="90"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="custom-selector"> Rank 11-20</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="custom-selector2"> Down</td>
        <td><button id="reset" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Set interval</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="custom-selector"> Rank 21-100</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="custom-selector2"> No movement</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="custom-selector"> Not in top 100</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Here is my script:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#slider").slider({
         min: 0,
         max: 1000,
         step: 1,
         range: true,
         values: [10, 90],
         tooltip: 'always',
         slide: function(event, ui) {
             for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
                 $("input.sliderValue[data-index=" + i + "]").val(ui.values[i]);
             }
         }
     });

     $("input.sliderValue").change(function() {
         var $this = $(this);
         $("#slider").slider("values", $this.data("index"), $this.val());
     });
 });
```

I need to be able to both specify in textboxes the value and use the sliders, along with a reset button.
[image]

Is looks like I wanted it to, but moving the slider doesn't change the text boxes and vice versa, what am I missing?

Comment: JSfiddle is working for me in both ways. It is changing values on sliding and also sliding when changing text box values. I m using firefox browser. Which browser you are trying this?

Comment: JSfiddle is also working on Chrome, i just tested ist.

Comment: I meant that the JSfiddle found here on stack WORKS, but not on my offline files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JSFiddle you link, the element with an ID of "slider" is an empty div which jQueryUI correctly populates with custom slider markup. But in your code the element is an input. Replace it with an empty div as shown in the docs:

https://jqueryui.com/slider/

Comment: replaced it with an empty div of id "slider", it changes the slider to the default one but it still won't change the textbox values

Comment: looks like I was missing the jquery-ui.js , i only had the .css

Comment: Tricky. So did my answer help, or is your slider still buggy?

Comment: It did help. Turns out jquery-ui just needs the div :)

Answer (score 2):

I try the code, but this part is not working (I am working on Firefox) when I put alert :

```
slide: function(event, ui) { alert(); // this alert is not show up!!
             for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
                 $("input.sliderValue[data-index=" + i + "]").val(ui.values[i]);
             }
         }
```

So I change it. Try this. It's working for me :

```
$("#slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step: 1,
    range: true,
    values: [10, 90],
});

$('#slider').on('slide', function (ev) {
   console.log(this.value[0]);
   console.log(this.value[1]);
   $('.sliderValue[data-index="0"]').val(this.value[0]);
   $('.sliderValue[data-index="1"]').val(this.value[1]);

});
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I figured it out 6 months ago!

Comment: @crystyxn,,  Would you please post your solution. It would help others.

Comment: I did it how Lincoln suggested above. I did not get it to work perfectly tho